# Como puedo manejar subindices en los mensajes que deseo imprimirle al usuario en javascript

Tags: javascript

Buena tarde,

Tengo una duda,en código JavaScript si deseo imprimirle al usuario un mensaje que diga metros cuadrados pero ese "cuadrados" en un superindice de la letra m, es posible?

Este es el ejemplo de como debe quedar :

[image: Ejemplo]

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si con: `<sup></sup>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si por *... mostrarle un mensaje al usuario ...* te refieres en **javascript** a través de un **alert** puedes utilizar caracteres **Unicode**, por ejemplo:

```js
alert("La habitación tiene 9 m\xB2 de superficie");
```

Si es a través de **HTML** puedes indicárselo mediante la etiqueta **superscript** en otras respuestas mencionada o también mediante **entidades HTML** o representación *hexadecimal*, por ejemplo:

- Elemento Superscript (**<sup>**): "El del estadio **Santiago Bernabéu** tiene 7140 m<sup>2</sup> de superficie"
- Entidades HTML (**&sup2;**): "El estadio **Santiago Bernabéu** tiene 7140 m² de superficie"
- Representación hexadecimal (**&#xB2;**): "El estadio **Santiago Bernabéu** tiene 7140 m² de superficie"

y posíblemente algunas más ...

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario código de alta complejidad en Javascript, con que uses la etiqueta de superscript `<sup></sup>` en alguna función de Javascript que inserte HTML, como `innerHTML`

```html
<p> El área del cuadrado es de 35 m<sup>2</sup>
```

Me imagino que es la posición que ocupas, porque para subíndice quedaría abajo y ese se usa para otro tipo de sintaxis matemática, te dejo el ejemplo de subscript `<sub></sub>`

```html
<p>3x<sub>3</sub>y<sub>5</sub>z<sub>2</sub></p>
```